# Kafka - NullPointerException in Send

Tags: apache-kafka

I'm using Kafka from a Spark application to send some notifications to a topic. I see loads of the following exception in my Spark logs, and the message is not delivered to the topic.

15/09/08 03:29:24 ERROR Sender: Uncaught error in kafka producer I/O thread:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.NetworkReceive.complete(NetworkReceive.java:48)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.poll(Selector.java:249)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.poll(NetworkClient.java:192)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:191)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:122)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I'm not sure what causes this error and looking at the source, it seems that either size or buffer variable in NetworkReceive.java is null.

Scanning through the logs, I see that prior to this log entry, there's one occurrence of the following message.

```
15/09/08 03:29:24 ERROR Sender: Uncaught error in kafka producer I/O thread: 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Invalid request (size = -2097152000)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.NetworkReceive.readFrom(NetworkReceive.java:68)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.poll(Selector.java:248)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.poll(NetworkClient.java:192)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:191)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:122)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
15
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By mistake I have switched the argument order of my Spark application, and Kafka was trying to connect to 9042 instead of 9092 port which it should connect to. I had Cassandra running on 9042 and it established the connection to it, but failed right after because the message was not what Kafka expected.

So if anyone else faces the same issue, double check your Kafka broker IP and Port :)

Comment: Exactly what happened with me!

Answer (score 0):

This is related to your hostname and port. Please verify your port, is your process running on the same port or not.